# Is there any way to calculate a Spearman's correlation between each matrix column?

Tags: r, matrix

Trying to calculate correlation between columns, but the cor() function only allows for comparison between two columns at a time.

```
> mat <- matrix(c(45,34,1,3,4325,23,1,2,5,7,3,4,32,734,2,53),ncol=4)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   45 4325    5   32
[2,]   34   23    7  734
[3,]    1    1    3    2
[4,]    3    2    4   53
```

Answer (score 5):

```
cor(mat, method = "spearman")
```

The `cor` function by default calculates the correlation between columns.  I don't know where you're getting the `corr` function from but it seems like `cor` should take care of your needs.

Comment: @SteveHwang If you read `?cor` you may find the `use` argument, well, useful.

Comment: @SteveHwang Do you have zeros in the matrix? These will give `-Inf` when logged.

Comment: @JasonMorgan I have no idea how to check. The matrix is 40,000x500.

Comment: You can't log negative values and expect to get a reasonable answer. Surely you have an idea whether negative / 0 values are possible?

Comment: @SteveHwang Try a simple summary on the non-transformed matrix: `summary(as.vector(mymatrix))`